# How to update MAC(mac osx only not ios) app store apps programmatically in macOS?

Tags: macos, app-store

How can I update app store apps programmatically, as a feature of my tool/app, without using any third party application, only Apple APIs for Mac app (macOS) store, not iOS?

I tried using curl to download resource on page but it didn't work.
I tried the software update command line tool. It worked for some apps and didn't work for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can update Mac apps as an integrated feature of your app by implementing the Sparkle framework in your app, which can be added via the Swift Package Manager in Xcode. This framework is based on standard macOS API's. More info can be found here: [sparkle-project.org](https://sparkle-project.org)